# Wso2is admin REST API Postman collection is available to public

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to create a new interface for wso2is for my specific requirement. I only need some specific functionalities (add user, add roles etc) from wso2, I go through several documentation in wso2 website and find:

- [this document](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Managing+Users+and+Roles+with+APIs#ManagingUsersandRoleswithAPIs-getUserList())
- [this post](https://medium.com/@inthiraj1994/postman-for-wso2-is-server-cdb2ba77acf2)

but never got a complete documentation.

Is it possible to get the postman collections for the same?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation you have referred to is relevant to the admin services for user and role management. They are implemented using SOAP. But since you have some basic requirements as add user delete user add roles you can use the SCIM2 REST API's[1][2]

[1].https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Using+the+SCIM+2.0+REST+APIs
[2].https://medium.com/@vindulajayawardana/scim-2-0-api-for-wso2-identity-server-5-3-0-fc5dcaad9e44